# Display matrix in coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm searching for a possibility to display four textual quadrants in a 2D coordinate system. In fact it's a 2x2 matrix with labels.

The figure I wish to have looks like:
[image: Wanted figure]

I guees there is an easy way to achieve this using tkiz.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Of course there is easy way to draw this :-). What you try so far? For starting point search this site for similar images and for example see http://www.texample.net/.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414403/drawing-vectors-on-3-d-coordinate-system

Comment: First you need to pick a graphics package such as TikZ (PGF), PStricks or pict2e.  You could just add all the elements using x.y coordinates.  You could use a standard plot axis (data visualization or pgfplots) and use graphics instead of graphis.  You could use a TikZ matrix for the text and put the arrows and dashed lines in later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every first question should be helped. Hope you will post MWE in the next question.
The code is self-explained.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[cell/.style={draw=teal,fill=teal!50,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1.5cm,rounded corners=2mm,font=\sffamily\bfseries}]
\def\a{1.5}
\def\b{1}
\path
(\a,\b) node[cell]{Swift}
(\a,-\b) node[cell]{Java} +(-90:1.3) node{high}
(-\a,\b) node[cell]{F\#} +(180:1.8) node[rotate=90]{high}
(-\a,-\b) node[cell]{Fortran} +(-90:1.3) node{low} +(180:1.8) node[rotate=90]{low}
;
\draw[dashed] (2*\a,0)--(-2*\a,0) (0,2*\b)--(0,-2*\b);
\draw[-latex] (-2*\a,-2*\b)--+(0:4.25*\a);  
\draw[-latex] (-2*\a,-2*\b)--+(90:4.25*\b);
\path 
(0,-2.8) node{\bfseries Popularity of language} 
(-4,0) node[rotate=90]{\bfseries Newness of language}   
;
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

While you definitely shouldn't ask "do it for me" questions and present some abstract issue you encountered while coding after searching by yourself how to do such a figure, I wanted to practice a bit with this example.
It is definitely not optimal and could be improved:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \tikzset{%
            language block/.style = {%
                rectangle,
                draw = blue,
                fill = blue!50!white,
                rounded corners,
                minimum width = 2cm,
                minimum height = 1cm
            }
        }
    
        \node[
            matrix,
            column sep = 0.5cm,
            row sep = 0.25cm,
        ] (graphmat) {
            \node[language block] (fs) {F\#}; & \node[language block] (s) {Swift};\\
            \node[language block] (f) {Fortran}; & \node[language block] (j) {Java};\\
        };
    
        \draw[Latex-Latex] (graphmat.north west) |- (graphmat.south east);
        
        \coordinate (highbottom) at ($(graphmat.south west)!0.75!(graphmat.south east)$);
        \coordinate (lowbottom) at ($(graphmat.south west)!0.25!(graphmat.south east)$);

        \coordinate (highleft) at ($(graphmat.south west)!0.75!(graphmat.north west)$);
        \coordinate (lowleft) at ($(graphmat.south west)!0.25!(graphmat.north west)$);
    
        \node[below] (hbtext) at (highbottom) {high};
        \node[below] (lbtext) at (lowbottom) {low};
        
        \node[
            above,
            rotate = 90
        ] (hltext) at (highleft) {high};
        \node[
            above,
            rotate = 90
        ] (lltext) at (lowleft) {low};
        
        \coordinate (pop) at ($(lbtext)!0.5!(hbtext)$);
        \node[below] at ([yshift = -0.2cm] pop) {\textbf{Popularity of language}};
        
        \coordinate (new) at ($(lltext)!0.5!(hltext)$);
        \node[
            above,
            rotate = 90
        ] at ([xshift = -0.2cm] new) {\textbf{Newness of language}};
    
        \draw[dashed] (graphmat.south) -- (graphmat.north);
        \draw[dashed] (graphmat.west) -- (graphmat.east);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, a solution using a `matrix` to distribute inner nodes and as reference for all additional lines and labels.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, matrix}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily, >=LaTeX]
\matrix (lang) [matrix of nodes, column sep=3mm, row sep=3mm,
    nodes={anchor=center, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, rounded corners=3mm,
        fill=cyan!90!black, draw=cyan!50!black, line width=.5mm}]
{F\# & Swift \\
Fortran & Java \\};
\draw [->, shorten >=-3mm](lang.south west)--(lang.south east); 
\node[below] at (lang.south-|lang-1-1.center) {low}; 
\node[below] at (lang.south-|lang-1-2.center) {high};
\draw [->, shorten >=-3mm](lang.south west)--(lang.north west);
\node[rotate=90, above] at (lang.west|-lang-2-1.center) {low};
\node[rotate=90, above] at (lang.west|-lang-1-1.center) {high};
\draw[dashed] (lang.south) node[below=5mm, font=\bfseries\sffamily]{Popularity of language}--(lang.north);
\draw[dashed] (lang.west) node[rotate=90, above=5mm, font=\bfseries\sffamily]{Newness of language} --(lang.east);
%\node
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]